# import.php parameter missing?

Tags: php, database, windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

Whenever I try to delete or update any of my tables in phpMyAdmin I receive the following error:

```
1.import.php: Missing parameter: import_type.


2.tbl-alter.php missing parameters:field
```

I have looked at the php.ini config file and changed the following settings:

```
session.save_path ="c:/xampp/tmp" to session.save_path ="C:/xampp/session/data"
```

Why is phpMyAdmin not letting me delete or update any of the tables within the database?

Comment: What application is this?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a corrupted installation of phpmyadmin.

Make sure your permissions are set correctly. Also consider reinstalling phpmyadmin using the latest stable build.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old post, but others with the same problem might find the solution useful.

After spending ages with various fixes to session.inc.php I finally had a eureka moment and thought to check the PHP session save directory was correct and writeable. Setting NTFS permissions to Everyone on the folder has fixed it for me.. Doh.

Comment: You have vastly improved my day with this answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using?

If using windows, try to reinstall your PHPMyAdmin
If not using windows, change user permission on your phpmyadmin folder, don't change it to 777 it will return you a error.

Comment: @gerep, I am using windows.